# How to find the exact command line that executed for opening a port?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I'm trying to start a node server, and I see that the port already been used.

I have many node process opened, and I wish to know which of them is using the port (without trial and error).

I'm looking for a command like that:

```
$ showcommandthatupenedaport -p 9229a

~/myproject/node server.js    pid: 343434
```

There is a command in that can give me output like this (bash scripts are very welcome)

Comment: How about "fuser -n tcp Portnumber" ?

Answer (score 0):

Aminadav:

You can try with (all are examples of my server):

- ps command if you have the pid and you want to know the name of the service.

e.g:

```
$ -> ps -p 31232 -o comm=
apache2
```

- fuser: If you want to check the services that are using a port:

```
$ -> $ -> lsof -t -i :80
871
31230
31232
```

You can use both in one for loop:

```
$ -> for pid in $(lsof -t -i :80); do ps -p $pid -o comm=; done
apache2
apache2
apache2
```

There are more commands like netstat or ss, but I think It's enough.

I hope been helpful.